# The Model tables in Django got deleted

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-database

The database table created automatically by django from model definition,i kind of deleted it using mysql command line.Now when i'm running a migration it says table doesn't exist .I used makemigrations,syncdb ,nothing works.How do i make django to create that table with those columns again..without me have to creating them manually.

Comment: You'll need to migrate back to a migration that created that table in the first place, hope for the best, then migrate up

Comment: I wonder how you managed to "kind of" delete the table. :)

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz i deleted it manually ...just experimenting

Comment: @Sayse the first  migrate itself fails....i used "python migrate.py migrate <appname> zero" to go back to the very fast migrate

Answer (score 1):

Ok I resolved it, i deleted the migration files from app->migrations folder ,deleted the database from "mysql" .Now i created new migration using "makemigrations" command, and then applied it to my db using "migrate" command.